# truffle compile Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

truffle compile outputs Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.

```
Compilation warnings encountered:

zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol:38:5: Warning: 
Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
   Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix was by removing zeppelin-solidity and reinstalling version zeppelin-solidity 1.8.0

```
npm install --save zeppelin-solidity@1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the **pragma solidity;** version. From ^0.4.21, compiler will issue a warning if events are not called with "emit" keyword explicitly.

Comment: any idea what this means? is it more secure if i use emit? how do i use emit? thanks in advance!

Comment: You should set **"pragma solidity version ^0.4.18"** to your .sol files. The warning comes from you using an import that does not uses "emit" for events and a compiler version that warns if emit is not present.

Answer (score 0):

`emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);`
This should work.